# Give a url a subdomain name without it being a subdomain

Tags: php, url, dns, subdomain

I know the title probably doesn't make much sense but I can't think of another way of putting it so I'll try to be more clear.

Basically I'm setting up a website for both premium & non-premium members and I'd like to give premium members something extra (as well as give them some added SEO). So, I want members to have the regular path such as:

http://www.mysite.com?user=username

And give premuim members a more direct path without actually setting up a subdomain or another folder:

username.mysite.com or http://www.mysite.com/username

How is this possible and how would you get/parse the "username" using php on page load? Thank you

Comment: You can do this with .htaccess mod rewrite to turn ?username=someone to /someone and as for subdomain you will need a wild card subdomains an easy guide to follow is here  https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains

Comment: two words mod rewrite is your friend, there is plenty of such examples on SO

Comment: Use mod_rewrite and a `RewriteRule` and a [catchall dns](http://serverfault.com/questions/175230/how-to-set-up-a-dns-to-use-a-catch-all-address) entry. Ask again when you can concretise your question with a preliminary coding attempt.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with  create sub domain with wild card  for this here is the steps

create sub domain in your cpanel with "*"  resulting this step it creates folder in ftp called

"wildcard" and now you can create code in wildcard folder and watch out the premium user

Comment: try this then down it